# Offline voice recognition functionality?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

If anyone has any input on if it is possible to include offline voice recognition in Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows UWP 10 I would appreciate any input!  The online functionality works great for windows phone 8.1, but the app I am developing will need to be used offline in some cases.

Comment: What types of constraints are you using when performing speech recognition? Predefined grammars like predefined dictation and web-search grammars need to be online, but programmatic list constraints and SRGS grammars can be used offline.

Comment: Thanks, that was the direction I needed to make it work.  the programmatic list works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **no**.

**Predefined grammars** like **dictation grammar** and **web-search grammars** are online. They can't work offline.

> These predefined grammars can be used to recognize up to 10 seconds of speech input and require no authoring effort on your part. However, they do require connection to a network.

I don't know the details of your requirement. But you can try to use **Custom grammars** like **Programmatic list constraints** and **SRGS grammar** to implement it as they can work without Internet. For more info, please see [Speech interactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-interactions#Constraints) and the official [Speech recognition and synthesis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) in GitHub.

Also you can vote on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=offline%20speech%20recognition%20) to ask for the offline voice recognition feature.

Comment: The SRGS grammar functionality is actually what was needed as what I was trying to recognize was a few simple categories that could be easily defined within the grxml.  Thanks again!